# I am attempting to make a registration form but when I run it this error appears Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on nul

Tags: php, error-handling, phpmyadmin

Here is the code for my SQL query I tried switching the variable but it didn't seem to work

````
```

    if (isset($_POST["Submit"])) {
        $dbhost = "localhost";
        $dbuser = "root";
        $dbpass = "";
        $db     = "test";
        $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db) or die("connect failed: %s\n" . $conn->error);
    }
    
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO test (CustomerId,Username,Password,FirstNmae,LastName,Country,Email,) VALUES('$CustomerId', '$Username', '$Password', '$FirstName','$LastName','$Country','$Email')";
    
    
    if ($conn->query($sql) === 1) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
    ```
````

Comment: Show your code please (in particular the part / block with the query string)

Comment: Your connection variable `$conn` is not set. Can't say why without more code. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

**First off**, you have an extra comma in your query string after the word Email (Email`,`)

So change

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO test (CustomerId,Username,Password,FirstNmae,LastName,Country,Email,) VALUES(....)";
```

to

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO test (CustomerId,Username,Password,FirstNmae,LastName,Country,Email) VALUES(....)";
```

**Secondly** , you should consider enclosing the whole query statements inside the following if block :

```
   if (isset($_POST["Submit"])) {
//// should put all the query statements
}
```

Right now if $_POST["Submit"] is not set, then $conn->query($sql) will definitely fail because you have not declared $conn

Last but not least, please change your insert query to parameterized prepared statement to avoid SQL injection attacks. You may draw reference from this official documentation:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: the errors have gone but when i click submit it does nothing